# GSheet - making sure all but one sheet is hidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a gradebook program in GSheet and have run into a new snag. I need to hide all the sheets but a "Student Report" sheet and then pdf and email them. It was working great, until I got a report that the script did not complete hiding the sheets and then continued on to make the pdfs. I added in a "sleep" but was hoping for a more proactive approach.

I came up with this idea but it just times out. What I am hoping is to have a do-while loop that keeps checking on the hidden attribute of the sheets....once all but one is hidden (i.e. Student Report)....it should go ahead. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var sheetName = "Student Report";

for(var i=0;i<sheets.length; i++){
if(sheets[i].getName()!=sheetName){
  sheets[i].hideSheet();
  }}
 var StudentReport = ss.getSheetByName("Student Report");
 ss.setActiveSheet(StudentReport);
 do {

 for (var k=0;k<sheets.length;k++){   
      var CountVisible = sheets.length;
    if(sheets[k].isSheetHidden()){
        CountVisible = CountVisible -1;
        Logger.log(CountVisible);
       }} 

  } while (CountVisible!=0);
//added wait time to esnure all sheets are properly hidden before next step
// Utilities.sleep(400);
```

Alternately, if someone knows how to just pdf a single sheet...that would solve the problem nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient to hide all but one sheet.

```
function hideAllSheetsExceptThisOne(sheetName) {
  var sheetName=sh||'Student Report';//default for testing
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length; i++){
    if(sheets[i].getName()!=sheetName){
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: It does and I have something similar but it seems the script doesn't wait for all the sheets to be hidden and then are pdf'ed thereby possibly exposing data. It's a very strange bug and I can't reproduce it but I have seen the end results. That is why I am trying to get it to verify all sheets are hidden.

Comment: Oh boy...I used that in other spots but didn't think of it for this problem. I've tested it and it "seems" fine. Will let it out into the wild and await feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar earlier this year, and this code proved to be very helpful. https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885

Comment: I did try to get that to work but I would change a student name, wait for the "Student Report" page to update and then Blob it...but the Blobs would all be the first student only. I had to abandon that solution and took to hiding, changing the student's names and then pdfing.